# Beginning wit PDO, first program doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I began learning PDO today.
This is my first program actually, and I'm stuck in the first program.

Here's a simple form which adds a single value to a database. When I click submit button, it gives *Could not execute because of*   (The errorInfo function returns nothing)

**Database Structure**

```
Column    Type
id         int unsigned auto_increment
name       varchar(255)
```

**fillvalues.html**

```
<form action="fillvalues.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="test">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**fillvalues.php**

```
<?php

include 'dbconnector.php';
//fill values
var_dump($db);

$sql="INSERT INTO test('name') VALUES ('" . $_POST['test'] . "')";
$smt=$db->query($sql);
if(!$smt)
{
    $ei = $db->errorInfo();
    die('Could not execute because of') . $ei[2];
}
else
{
    echo "Added";
}

var_dump($smt);
var_dump($sql);

?>
```

**dbconnector.php**

```
<?php

try
{
    $db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pdo",'root','');
}
catch(PDOException $pe)
{
    die('Could not connect to the database') . $pe->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.fcom/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @Quentin

I should probably use prepared statements right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have syntax error in your query. you shouldn't quote column names with apostrophe:

```
INSERT INTO test(name) VALUES ('" . $_POST['test'] . "')
```

Comment: I answered the question, pointed out why his query is not executing. i do not deserve downvote because his implementation of this query has vulnerabilities. you can answer yourself and point that out as well.

Comment: You are downvoted for `you shouldn't quote colum names` which is false

Comment: added `you shouldn't quote colum names with apostrophe`.

Comment: by the way, `'` is called quotation mark whereas ` is called grave accent. get your facts straight. my remark is **correct**

Answer (score 0):

this is how your statement should be if your using

```
PDO for mysql

$sql="INSERT INTO test(name) VALUES(:myval)";
$smt=$db->prepare($sql);
$smt->bindParam(':myval', $_POST['test'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$smt->execute();
```

Comment: you can't quote column names with apostrophe.

Comment: oops my mistake now see